# Flink sql api window TVF left outer join : doesn't support consuming update changes which is produced by node GroupAggregate

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I attempted to do something similar as shown in below example provide in latest release Doc :

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-join/#innerleftrightfull-outer

PFB query that will be sent as a kafka sink output table:

```sql
SELECT cdr.org_id orgid, cdr.cluster_id clusterid, cdr.c_id cid,
    MIN(scalarGradeFunc(cmr.metrics, cdr.duration, cmr.duration)) grade 
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE cdrTable, DESCRIPTOR(proctime), INTERVAL '1' MINUTES))) cdr                  
    LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT * FROM TABLE(TUMBLE(TABLE cmrTable, DESCRIPTOR(proctime), INTERVAL '1' MINUTES))) cmr 
    ON (cdr.org_id = cmr.org_id AND cdr.cluster_id = cmr.cluster_id AND cdr.c_id = cmr.c_id ) 
       AND cdr.window_start = cmr.window_start AND cdr.window_end = cmr.window_end 
GROUP BY cdr.org_id, cdr.cluster_id, cdr.c_id;
```

Trying to use window tvf to join two tables as window join and I have one min agg function in select, So I have used group by for aggregation while trying it out getting below error :

`'default_catalog.default_database.outputCdrTable' doesn't support consuming update changes which is produced by node GroupAggregate(groupBy=[orgid, ...])`

one more approach tried(Group Window Aggregation) but that seems to be deprecated as per release note :
https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/window-agg/#group-window-aggregation

Please help me on this !!!

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved now used upsert kafka with primary key for sink

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).